# How to deploy an artifact into Amazon S3 with Maven?

Tags: maven, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, maven-3

I'm trying to follow these tutorials ([1](http://jmchung.github.io/blog/2015/03/01/using-amazon-s3-as-a-private-maven-repository/),[2](http://www.yegor256.com/2015/09/07/maven-repository-amazon-s3.html)) to achieve the mentioned goal. But I'm still getting this error from Maven:

```
INFO] Installing /home/valter/temp-workspace/document-engine/target/application-1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT.jar to /home/valter/.m2/repository/com/company-solutions/application/1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/application-1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /home/valter/temp-workspace/document-engine/pom.xml to /home/valter/.m2/repository/com/company-solutions/application/1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/application-1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ application ---
Downloading: s3://myrepo.company.solutions/snapshot/com/company-solutions/application/1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] s3://myrepo.company.solutions/snapshot - Connection refused
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata com.company-solutions:application:1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to s3.snapshot (s3://myrepo.company.solutions/snapshot): Could not connect to repository
[INFO] Logged off - myrepo.company.solutions
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:31 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-11-16T18:36:26+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 181M/1289M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project application: Failed to retrieve remote metadata com.company-solutions:application:1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could not transfer metadata com.company-solutions:application:1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to s3.snapshot (s3://myrepo.company.solutions/snapshot): Could not connect to repository: Status Code: 400, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: 709B60A05E8E7062, AWS Error Code: InvalidRequest, AWS Error Message: The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

These are my local files, **~.m2/settings.xml** (with fictious values, of course):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 
      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>s3.site</id>
            <username>access_key</username>
            <password>private_key</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>s3.release</id>
            <username>access_key</username>
            <password>private_key</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>s3.snapshot</id>
            <username>access_key</username>
            <password>private_key</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

And my **pom.xml**:

```
<project>
    <build>
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>org.kuali.maven.wagons</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-s3-wagon</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
        ...
    </build>
    <distributionManagement>
        <site>
            <id>s3.site</id>
            <url>s3://myrepo.company.solutions/site</url>
        </site>
        <repository>
            <id>s3.release</id>
            <url>s3://myrepo.company.solutions/release</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>s3.snapshot</id>
            <url>s3://myrepo.company.solutions/snapshot</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
...
</project>
```

I'm using Maven 3.3.3.

**EDIT**
This is my policy simulator result:
[image]

Comment: s3://myrepo.company.solutions/snapshot - Connection refused  - Are you sure that the IAM user you're using has the relevant S3 permissions? Or are you sure that the bucket in question doesn't have a bucket policy that is overriding permissions allowed in the IAM policy?

Comment: @mickzer Yes, I'm sure that my IAM user has the permission to do everythin in that bucket and my bucket has no policy so far.

Answer (score 6):

Just to let you guys know what happened. 
The problem was the region of my bucket was **Frankfurt**, which requires the newest version of authentication from Amazon AWS, version 4. As far as I can tell, the plugin `aws-maven` doesn't support this new version right now. So the solutions was to move my bucket to another region which support the older version of schemes, like **US Standard**. And everything seems to work fine now!

Comment: Exactly what happened to me as well. On a side note did you build any maven projects that consume this private maven repository? If so, what url did you use under the tag "repository" inside the pom.xml? Thank you!