# How do I deploy jars to S3 with maven?

Tags: java, maven, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a project that is using Maven to build and I need to publish it to a private S3 repository.

I found [AWS Maven Wagon](https://github.com/spring-projects/aws-maven) but when I try to deploy I get an authentication error:

```
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ custom-file-extension-windows-bundler ---
Downloading from aws-snapshot: s3://project-x-support/maven2/de/dynamicfiles/projects/javafx/bundler/custom-file-extension-windows-bundler/1.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Uploading to aws-snapshot: s3://project-x-support/maven2/de/dynamicfiles/projects/javafx/bundler/custom-file-extension-windows-bundler/1.0.1-SNAPSHOT/custom-file-extension-windows-bundler-1.0.1-20180119.133946-1.jar
Uploading to aws-snapshot: s3://project-x-support/maven2/de/dynamicfiles/projects/javafx/bundler/custom-file-extension-windows-bundler/1.0.1-SNAPSHOT/custom-file-extension-windows-bundler-1.0.1-20180119.133946-1.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.773 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-01-19T13:39:46Z
[INFO] Final Memory: 23M/254M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project custom-file-extension-windows-bundler: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact de.dynamicfiles.projects.javafx.bundler:custom-file-extension-windows-bundler:jar:1.0.1-20180119.133946-1 from/to aws-snapshot (s3://project-x-su
pport/maven2): Cannot write directory 'maven2/': Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: CE401778F4180C1E) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I'm pretty sure the credentials and permissions are correct because I'm using them to deploy a jar with Gradle (I copied from .aws/credentials to .m2/settings.xml). My full `pom.xml` file looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>de.dynamicfiles.projects.javafx.bundler</groupId>
    <artifactId>custom-file-extension-windows-bundler</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <developers>
        <developer>
            <name>Danny Althoff</name>
            <email>fibrefox@dynamicfiles.de</email>
            <url>https://www.dynamicfiles.de</url>
        </developer>
    </developers>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <version.java.source>1.8</version.java.source>
        <version.java.target>1.8</version.java.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${version.java.source}</source>
                    <target>${version.java.target}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                            <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <display_version>${display_version}</display_version>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>org.springframework.build</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-maven</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javafx-packager</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-packager</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0_40</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/ant-javafx.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>aws-release</id>
            <name>AWS Release Repository</name>
            <url>s3://project-x-support/maven2</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>aws-snapshot</id>
            <name>AWS Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>s3://project-x-support/maven2</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

I've noticed that AWS Maven Wagon is quite old and using an obsolete authentication mechanism:

- https://github.com/spring-projects/aws-maven/issues/48
- https://github.com/spring-projects/aws-maven/issues/44
- https://github.com/spring-projects/aws-maven/issues/50

so, I also tried with:

```
<groupId>org.zalando.org.springframework.build</groupId>
<artifactId>aws-maven</artifactId>
<version>5.0.0.RELEASE-zal-2</version>
```

but I get the same result.

My credentials are configured in C:\Users\pupeno.m2\settings.xml and look like this:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>aws-release</id>
      <username>BLAHBLAH</username>
      <password>SECRETBLAHBLAH</password>
    </server>
    <server>
      <id>aws-snapshot</id>
      <username>BLAHBLAH</username>
      <password>SECRETBLAHBLAH</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

My relevant policies looks like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutAnalyticsConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging",
                "s3:CreateBucket",
                "s3:ReplicateObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:DeleteBucketWebsite",
                "s3:PutLifecycleConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
                "s3:PutObjectTagging",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetIpConfiguration",
                "s3:DeleteObjectTagging",
                "s3:GetBucketWebsite",
                "s3:PutReplicationConfiguration",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersionTagging",
                "s3:GetBucketNotification",
                "s3:PutBucketCORS",
                "s3:GetReplicationConfiguration",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutBucketNotification",
                "s3:PutBucketLogging",
                "s3:GetAnalyticsConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionForReplication",
                "s3:GetLifecycleConfiguration",
                "s3:ListBucketByTags",
                "s3:GetInventoryConfiguration",
                "s3:GetBucketTagging",
                "s3:PutAccelerateConfiguration",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetBucketLogging",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:ReplicateTags",
                "s3:RestoreObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetAccelerateConfiguration",
                "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionTorrent",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:PutBucketTagging",
                "s3:GetBucketRequestPayment",
                "s3:GetObjectTagging",
                "s3:GetMetricsConfiguration",
                "s3:DeleteBucket",
                "s3:PutBucketVersioning",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:PutMetricsConfiguration",
                "s3:PutObjectVersionTagging",
                "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
                "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                "s3:PutInventoryConfiguration",
                "s3:PutIpConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectTorrent",
                "s3:PutBucketWebsite",
                "s3:PutBucketRequestPayment",
                "s3:GetBucketCORS",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ReplicateDelete",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::project-x-support/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::project-x-support"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:HeadBucket",
                "s3:ListObjects"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you try setting `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_KEY` as environment variables? and see whether it get picked up.

Comment: You didn't mention about the s3 bucket policy,did you verify if it's restricting upload from a particular user, or enforcing encryption or anything like that?

Would also be a good idea to check if you are able to upload to this bucket directly, without maven.

Comment: Also check whether you are configuring credentials in the correct settings.xml file `mvn -X`

Comment: If the age of the extension would be really the reason, maybe having a look on this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33741584/how-to-deploy-an-artifact-into-amazon-s3-with-maven is worth it.

Comment: You problem is here: `Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: CE401778F4180C1E) `,,,

Comment: @Abi: I use the same user to upload jars with Maven, so, no other restrictions are there.

Comment: @Anuruddha: I tried that, exactly the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

```
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>BUCKET_NAME.release</id>
      <username>ACCESSKEYID</username>
      <password>SECRETACCESSKEY</password>
      <filePermissions>BucketOwnerFullControl</filePermissions>
    </server>
    <server>
       <id>BUCKET_NAME.snapshot</id>
       <username>ACCESSKEYID</username>
       <password>SECRETACCESSKEY</password>
       <filePermissions>BucketOwnerFullControl</filePermissions>
    </server>
  </servers>
```